# Question with PIL.putdata() and For loop to append the modified images to a new list

Tags: for-loop, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have an image that I want to make 5 copies.

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image

image=Image.open("image.gif")
image=image.convert('RGB')
images=[]
for i in range(1, 6):
    images.append(image)
```

After making some changes to the intensity of each color in the RGB band, I want to load this data onto these 5 pictures (each item in the "RGB_band" list is a tuple containing different pixel modifications, and each tuple is unique from one another).

```
RGB_band= [modification_1,modification_2,modification_3, modification_4, modification_5]

new_images=[] #loop to load new pixel information onto the pictures and append to a new list.
for i in range(len(images)):
    images[i].putdata(RGB_band[i])
    new_images.append(images[i])
```

I was expecting each image in the "new_images" list to have different color intensity (i.e. first image should show the pixel data from modification_1, second image shows pixel data from modification_2, etc), but instead all 5 images in "new_images" list are the original image from the list "images" (unmodified). However, during the "For" loop, if I have it this way:

```
for i in range(len(images)):
    images[i].putdata(RGB_band[i])
    new_images.append(images[i])
    new_images[i].show()
```

Then the image shown during each iteration has the correct color (i.e. 5 images shown with 5 different colors)

Could anyone please tell me what the problem is? I tried different thing in the "For" loop but the images in "new_images" list still came out the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to do, but I think you have failed to realise that Python objects need to be **copied** in order to be unique objects with their own allocated memory.

Compare this, where each image in the list is sharing memory with the other items:

```
image=Image.open("image.png").convert('RGB') 
images=[]
for i in range(1, 6):
    images.append(image)
```

If you now look at the list - specifically the addresses on the right you can see they are all the same thing:

```
print(images)

[<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=1000x300 at 0x1084C3C10>,
 <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=1000x300 at 0x1084C3C10>,
 <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=1000x300 at 0x1084C3C10>,
 <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=1000x300 at 0x1084C3C10>,
 <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=1000x300 at 0x1084C3C10>]
```

And if we check whether they share memory:

```
print(images[0] is images[4])
True
```

Now look at this when I copy each image so that it is a unique copy with its own data:

```
Uimages=[]
for i in range(1, 6):
    Uimages.append(image.copy())
```

Now look at the list and see the addresses are different:

```
print(Images)
[<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=1000x300 at 0x108797790>,
 <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=1000x300 at 0x108797F50>,
 <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=1000x300 at 0x1087973D0>,
 <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=1000x300 at 0x108797510>,
 <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=1000x300 at 0x1084DB450>]
```

And check if they are the same object:

```
print(Uimages[0] is Uimages[4])
False
```

In general, if you start treating images as lists of pixels, you have probably already gone wrong. It is inefficient and slow. Consider using Numpy or OpenCV and using vectorised code.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Mark. I am working on a project that specifically requires modifying the intensity of one color in the RGB band (in this case, keeping G and B the sane, change the intensity of red by 0.2x and 0.3x and 0.5x, etc). Besides getting the pixel data from the image by using Image.getdata(), modifying the pixel data by multiplying R by the multipliers, then load the new pixels back onto the image, I don't know of another way of doing this.

Comment: Using Image.getdata() gives me a list that contains information in the format of [R,G,B]. For example, first pixel [200, 150, 50], second pixel [150, 100, 80], etc. I then multiply each pixel by 0.1x to get [20, 150, 50] for first pixel, [15, 10, 8] for second pixel, etc. This will give me a list that contains the new color. Then after that, I load this new information to the original image to create a new image with different intensity of Red.

Comment: Looks like you should be using a colour matrix https://stackoverflow.com/a/58877223/2836621 or split channels https://stackoverflow.com/a/59323838/2836621

Comment: I figured it out. Yes, it was exactly because I didn't make a copy of each image when appending to the new list. Thanks so much!